# C++ Builder XE2 - custom component as part of the project/project group

Tags: delphi, c++builder, custom-component, c++builder-xe2

Is it possible to use custom component derived from default one to be visible only as part of the project? The advantage of this solution is that I need not to distribute source code of component separately from that of application. Also there is no need for other developers to always check if they have installed the latest version. I need not to manage various versions and copy them somewhere to share my changes with other developers in team (whether it be network disk or SVN server). They get new version with every SVN update from server.
If i used delphi there would be solution - interposer class but this is not applicable to me. MS Visual Studio has possibility to use component only as part of Solution (analogy to MS VS Solution is ProjectGroup in C++ Builder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is only possible if the component is created dynamically at run-time only.  If the component needs to be accessible at design-time, then it must be installed into the IDE before the project can then use it.